# How to add another router on an existing subnet?

Tags: networking, iptables, subnet

What I am trying to do is basically this.
I am on a network who's routing table is something like this.

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         thebrain        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 wlan0
```

When I connect my router to the network, I get a routing table which looks something like this.

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         DD-WRT          0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.11.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
```

When I connect my computer to the personal router(DD-WRT) network, I get an IP address which is outside the 192.168.1 range. So that means that I can ping machines from my computer to the machines on the network( the ones with ip addresses as 192.168.1.xx), but I cannot do it the other way.

What I need to do is set up the routes so that I can ping the machines on 192.168.1.0 so that they can ping 192.168.11.123, or whatever my router is connected with. Currently it says that icmp packet filtered.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, the Buffalo WZR- 600DHP as my router. I have DD-WRT installed, but I don't mind changing the firmware to Openwrt if there is a good enough reason.

Comment: This question **really** needs clarifying before it can be answered.  At the very least, please replace the netstat output above with `netstat -rn`, so we can see addresses.  Better still, draw a small network diagram *as well*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should configure DD-WRT to be in 'Router' mode and not 'Gateway' -- This will disable NAT.

```
[Setup]->[Advanced Routing]->[Operating Mode]
```

You will need to add an iptables rule to allow traffic to pass from the existing router:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

On the existing router (192.168.1.1) you should create a static route using the DD-WRT's WAN IP.

```
Dest Network: 192.168.11.0 
Net Mask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.1.100 (DD-WRT's WAN IP)
```

You may need a static route on your DD-WRT, though a default route should work in this situation.